# SMTP Headers in VB.Net without Redemption

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, smtp

I'm writing a mail component for a VB.Net app, and need to handle mails differently that are "Sent on Behalf" of someone.  Although the Outlook Object Model exposes "SentOnBehalfOfName", it doesn't expose the email address for that party.  Supposedly it's in the "OtherHeaders" field of the SMTP header, but I don't see an easy way to get to those through the Mailitem object.  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

our hacky workaround right now has been to construct a dummy reply.  the reply-to field is populated based on the sentonbehalfof name, so then we can grab it and destroy the dummy.  inelegant for sure, but it works

Answer (score 0):

You could look up the name in AD or the GAL ?
or you could look up the PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS via a MailItem.PropertyAccessor id you are using 2007